# Twitter decode share url when sharing

Tags: twitter, urlencode, twitter-share

When using Twitter share url, I have the following:

> https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Hello+world&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fmaps%23hello

This would result in a Tweet as the following:

> Hello world http://www.google.com/maps#hello

Is it possible for me to keep '%23' relative to my URL. That is to have:

> Hello world http://www.google.com/maps%23hello

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use %25 to encode the "%"

```
    https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Hello%20world
&url=http://www.google.com/maps%2523hello
```

So "%2523" would make %23